# How to get Icon-Names for MIME-types in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, mime-type, icon-themes

is there a way to convert the output of

```
file --mime-type FILE
```

e.g.

```
"application/pdf"
```

into an icon-name, depending on the current icon-theme, or even a full link?

Where is that specified? I can't find anything like that in my index.theme files

Comment: You want the icon appear in the terminal or what?

Answer (score 2):

The icons are selected based on the mime-type name. The basic idea is that there should be an icon named `application-pdf.png` or similar in the path for the current theme.

For example, in my system there are a bunch of them, you can find them by

```
locate application-pdf | grep icons
```

Moreover, you can find the files for definition of characteristics of mime-types in `/usr/share/mime/`: for example for application-pdf you have `/usr/share/mime/application/pdf.xml`. I do not know if this file can contain an override for the icon.

I have published a little page for adding new MIME types, but I am not sure if publishing the link here is considered acceptable policy...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
locate $(file --mime-type "FILE" | awk "{print $NF}" | sed "s/\//-/g") | grep "/share/icons/"
```

Comment: Apparently I posted a dup question on this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912622/command-to-return-path-file-name-of-icon-matching-file-types I'm wondering if your answer has an update? For example running your answer on a plain text file returns 13 different icon file names.